# TypeScript class with a method not used in each instances

Tags: typescript, zeromq

I have a TypeScript class that is creating the basics of a ZMQ bus communication. I first wanted to make a general class that I can instantiate as many time as required. But now, i need to make more instances that does not totally fit the general class i made. Actually, the only difference is that in these new instances, the `request` method is never used depending on `type`. So, is it somehow possible to keep the same general class but to ignore the `request` method when it is not required ?

```
let zmq = require("zeromq")

class ZMQBus {
    socket:any
    port:number

    constructor(type:string, port:number) {
        this.socket = zmq.socket(type)
        this.port   = port
    }

    open(): void {
        this.socket.connect("tcp://localhost:" + this.port)

        this.socket.on("message", function(reply) {
            console.log("Received reply : " + reply.toString());
        })
    }

    request(msg:any): void {
        this.socket.send(msg);
    }

    close(): void {
        this.socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You *probably* want an interface that defines open and close, an interface that extends that interface that defines request, and two implementation classes, one for each interface. Hard to say for sure without knowing more details about the other class.

Comment: I actually wanted to avoid to make 2 class as it would imply quit the same as not implementating `request` in one of the tow. Then, what do you mean by "the other class", what details do you need ? `request` is simply not used by the rest of the code when type has a certain value

Comment: That is an *antipattern*. You're using Typescript, you have a strong-ish type system, why are you passing a type **string** [to a constructor](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped)? If two things are different types, give them different types *in the type system*. Otherwise you're doing a lot of extra typing for no benefit.

Comment: type cannot be other than a string. I mean, ZeroMQ is a third-party. 
Until now, I only needed to create REQ/REP socket, but it turns out that i now need a PUSH/PULL socket to fetch data. So in the later case, request is not required. I understand that it is not good programming, and if really it is awfull, i'll create tow dedicated class. I was juste wondering if keeping one general class is possible.

Comment: Third party libraries generally have to work with plain Javascript. If you are using Typescript, then use it: if zeromq has an enumerated set of string "types" it expects, then create a string enum and use *that* so at least the type system protects you. But yes, you should really make a separate class/type for each one since they have distinct semantics/implementations. Don't get me wrong, Typescript isn't the be-all-end-all, but if you're bearing the costs of static typing you should get the benefits too.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted to avoid two classes because you didn't want to imply that the two were different. The request being unimportant in certain cases does not make it harmful. You could still use a single class with a a single implementation of `request` that you only use when it is required. If you really need to stipulate that `request` is not present, you will have to create a separate type. You might achieve semantically what you want, without any antipatterns by utilizing a factory pattern and conditional types

```
type ZmqTypes = "REQUEST" | "NOREQUEST";

interface ZMQBus {
  open: () => void;
  close: () => void;
  request?: (msg: any) => void;
  type: ZmqTypes;
  port: number;
}

interface ZMQBusR extends ZMQBus {
  request: (msg: any) => void;
}

interface ZMQBusNoR extends Omit<ZMQBus, "request"> {}

class GenericZMQBus implements ZMQBus {
    socket:any
    port:number

    constructor(type:string, port:number) {
        this.socket = zmq.socket(type)
        this.port   = port
    }

    open(): void {
        this.socket.connect("tcp://localhost:" + this.port)

        this.socket.on("message", function(reply : any) {
            console.log("Received reply : " + reply.toString());
        })
    }

    close(): void {
        this.socket.close();
    }
}

class ZMQBusWithRequest extends GenericZMQBus implements ZMQBusR {
  request(msg : any) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

function createZMQBus<T extends ZmqTypes>(type: T, port: number) : T extends "REQUEST" ? ZMQBusR : ZMQBusNoR {
  if (type === "REQUEST") { 
    return new ZMQBusWithRequest(type, port) as unknown as T extends "REQUEST" ? ZMQBusR : ZMQBusNoR;
  }
  return new GenericZMQBus(type, port) as unknown as T extends "REQUEST" ? ZMQBusR : ZMQBusNoR;
}

const zmqObj = createZMQBus("REQUEST", 999);
const zmqObj1 = createZMQBus("NOREQUEST", 999);

zmqObj.request('hello');
zmqObj1.request('error'); // is an error
```

You still have multiple classes and interfaces with a strict type system, but a single way of creating those objects that implies a consistent purpose, if not a consistent implementation. And since both extend a single generic interface, you can pass either type around as a single ZMQType. You just have to make sure that you check for the correct presence of the `request` method before you try to use it.

```
function testZMQImplementation(z: ZMQBus) {
  if (z.request) {
    z.request('testing')
  }
}

testZMQImplementation(zmqObj);
testZMQImplementation(zmqObj1);
```